# Why does laravel files is in muted file name color after git clone from remote repo

Tags: laravel, git, github, laravel-backpack

I just cloned a git laravel project from a remote repository. After cloning it I did $composer install, $npm install, and $npm run dev. I even setup the .env file already but it's in a muted color with the vendor folder and node_modules(please see attached picture). When I tried to access the website it's not reloading.

[Image of the file name that it's in muted color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF8At.png)

I tried moving branches but I still have the muted file name color.
Do you think I need to make a copy of remote repository to my local repository?
what should I do? Do I still need to re install the laravel-backpack?

Comment: those are the files and folders excluded from being pushed to git, they are in the ``.gitignore`` file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OMi Shah for answering my question. So found different cause of the issue, it's because of user permissions.

Comment: What user permissions? What did you do to fix your issue?